# How can be difference when using variable directly for filtering?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

R makes this strange behaviour:

```
country=2
> Polity_data %>% filter(as.integer(ccode) == country) %>% head()
# A tibble: 0 × 37
# ℹ 37 variables: p5 <dbl>, cyear <dbl>, ccode <dbl>, scode <chr>, country <chr>, year <dbl>, flag <dbl>,
#   fragment <dbl>, democ <dbl>, autoc <dbl>, polity <dbl>, polity2 <dbl>, durable <dbl>, xrreg <dbl>,
#   xrcomp <dbl>, xropen <dbl>, xconst <dbl>, parreg <dbl>, parcomp <dbl>, exrec <dbl>, exconst <dbl>,
#   polcomp <dbl>, prior <dbl>, emonth <dbl>, eday <dbl>, eyear <dbl>, eprec <dbl>, interim <dbl>, bmonth <dbl>,
#   bday <dbl>, byear <dbl>, bprec <dbl>, post <dbl>, change <dbl>, d5 <dbl>, sf <dbl>, regtrans <dbl>
```

But when using country code directly, it is not empty, which is correct.

```
> Polity_data %>% filter(as.integer(ccode) == 2) %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 × 37
     p5 cyear ccode scode country  year  flag fragment democ autoc polity polity2 durable xrreg xrcomp xropen xconst
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 21776     2 USA   United…  1776     0        0   -77   -77    -77       0       0   -77    -77    -77    -77
2     1 21777     2 USA   United…  1777     0        0   -77   -77    -77       0       0   -77    -77    -77    -77
3     1 21778     2 USA   United…  1778     0        0   -77   -77    -77       0       0   -77    -77    -77    -77
4     1 21779     2 USA   United…  1779     0        0   -77   -77    -77       0       0   -77    -77    -77    -77
5     1 21780     2 USA   United…  1780     0        0   -77   -77    -77       0       0   -77    -77    -77    -77
6     1 21781     2 USA   United…  1781     0        0   -77   -77    -77       0       0   -77    -77    -77    -77
# ℹ 20 more variables: parreg <dbl>, parcomp <dbl>, exrec <dbl>, exconst <dbl>, polcomp <dbl>, prior <dbl>,
#   emonth <dbl>, eday <dbl>, eyear <dbl>, eprec <dbl>, interim <dbl>, bmonth <dbl>, bday <dbl>, byear <dbl>,
#   bprec <dbl>, post <dbl>, change <dbl>, d5 <dbl>, sf <dbl>, regtrans <dbl>
```

`

Searching for NA was not helpful:

```
Polity_data %>% 
+     mutate(ccode_is_numeric = !is.na(as.numeric(as.character(ccode)))) %>%
+     filter(ccode_is_numeric == FALSE)
# A tibble: 0 × 38
# ℹ 38 variables: p5 <dbl>, cyear <dbl>, ccode <dbl>, scode <chr>, country <chr>, year <dbl>, flag <dbl>,
#   fragment <dbl>, democ <dbl>, autoc <dbl>, polity <dbl>, polity2 <dbl>, durable <dbl>, xrreg <dbl>,
#   xrcomp <dbl>, xropen <dbl>, xconst <dbl>, parreg <dbl>, parcomp <dbl>, exrec <dbl>, exconst <dbl>,
#   polcomp <dbl>, prior <dbl>, emonth <dbl>, eday <dbl>, eyear <dbl>, eprec <dbl>, interim <dbl>, bmonth <dbl>,
#   bday <dbl>, byear <dbl>, bprec <dbl>, post <dbl>, change <dbl>, d5 <dbl>, sf <dbl>, regtrans <dbl>,
#   ccode_is_numeric <lgl>
```

Datatypes are also same:

```
> typeof(country)
[1] "double"
> typeof(Polity_data$ccode)
[1] "double"
```

But again, direct comparison works:

```
> typeof(sort(unique(Polity_data$ccode)))
[1] "double"
> country
[1] 2
> sort(unique(Polity_data$ccode))[1]
[1] 2
> sort(unique(Polity_data$ccode))[1]==2
[1] TRUE
> sort(unique(Polity_data$ccode))[1]==country
[1] TRUE
```

Any idea? I am not very skilled programmer, but now I am really confused...

Comment: Plus to add – I also tried to restart R session, everything is up to date, results still conflicted...

Comment: Try to add L to country's value. i.e 2L

Comment: I can't reproduce this, please include the dput of the head of your data

Comment: `mtcars %>% filter(as.integer(carb) == country)` works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your dataset contains a column `country`! So, when you try `filter(ccode == country)` it´s refering to `Polity_data$country <chr>` and not `country <- 2`.

Change the constant-name or the column-name and it works just fine:

```
# *Always* include minimum data!
aux <- tibble::tribble(
  ~p5, ~cyear, ~ccode, ~country, ~year,
  1,  21776,      1,    "USA",  1776,
  1,  21777,      1,    "USA",  1777,
  1,  21778,      2,    "USA",  1778,
  1,  21779,      2,    "USA",  1779,
  1,  21780,      3,    "USA",  1780,
  1,  21781,      3,    "USA",  1781)    

# The constants
country <- 2
not_country <- 2

# Different constant name
> filter(aux, ccode == not_country)
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     p5 cyear ccode country  year
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     1 21778     2 USA      1778
2     1 21779     2 USA      1779

# Different column name
aux <- rename(aux, not_country = country)
> filter(aux, ccode == country)
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     p5 cyear ccode not_country  year
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1     1 21778     2 USA          1778
2     1 21779     2 USA          1779
```

..and different names, but the same mistake:

```
> filter(aux, ccode == not_country)
# A tibble: 0 × 5
# ℹ 5 variables: p5 <dbl>, cyear <dbl>, ccode <dbl>, not_country <chr>, year <dbl>
```

**EDIT**:
As explained by @MrFlick on comments (thank you), with `dplyr`, *we can use `.env` and `.data` to disambiguate in this situation*:

```
year <-  1777

> filter(aux, year == .env$year)
# A tibble: 1 × 5
     p5 cyear ccode not_country  year
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1     1 21777     1 USA          1777
```

Comment: You don't need to rename. `dplyr` has the `.env` and `.data` pronouns to disambiguate  in this situation. Use `filter(aux, ccode == .env$country)` to get the value from the environment.